# Cutting off text in a form

Tags: css

I have looked across the web but can't figure out how to do this.

[Example Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9y5n.png)

How do I exactly get the User Login word cutting the form on top? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you encase your form's content inside `<fieldset></fieldset>` tags the box will appear around them.

If you add a `<legend></legend>` tag the words will appear.

Recreation of image:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
     <fieldset style=width:fit-content;>
        <legend>USER LOGIN</legend>
        <label>PDIN: </label>
        <input style=float:right; type=text><br><br>
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input style=float:right; type=text><br><br>
        <button>Login</button>
        <button>Reset</button>
        <button style=float:right;>New User</button>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope you find this helpful :D